# Can the app get Fragment.onAttached() before Application.onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Is there any dependency between Application's and Activity's/Fragment's lifecycle? Is it possible to get `Activity.onCreate()` or `Fragment.onAttached()` before `Application.onCreate()`?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: @azizbekian Yep, I hope so also. But is there any proof?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any dependency between Application's and Activity's/Fragment's lifecycle?

The `Application` singleton for your process will be created before any activities, let alone fragments.

> Is it possible to get Activity.onCreate() or Fragment.onAttached() before Application.onCreate()?

Not in any conventional scenario.

Comment: @tse: I do not know what in documentation you would consider to be "proof". [The JavaDocs for `Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) has "The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created." Unfortunately, that sentence is incorrect, and the story is more complicated than that. That is why I wrote "Not in any conventional scenario" instead of "No".

Comment: @CommonsWare, "Unfortunately, that sentence is incorrect" in what means? What scenario you have in your mind. Please share some links concerning the case if possible. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

The system should create the app process (that start with Application.onCreate() )
Then it Starr the main activity.

Comment: @azizbekian: Actually, I should rephrase that. The sentence might be correct. However, the OP's question is not about when the `Application` is *instantiated*, but instead when `onCreate()` is called on it. Other methods are called on an `Application` before `onCreate()` (notably `attachBaseContext()`). And any `ContentProviders` in your app have their `onCreate()` called before the `Application` is called with `onCreate()`. That's why we have to set up things like ACRA in `attachBaseContext()`.

Comment: And what about Fragments? Is is possible to have `Fragment.onCreate()` before `Application.onCreate()`?

Comment: @tse: A `Fragment` will not be created until its associated `Activity` has started to be created. Your activities and fragments will not be instantiated until after the `Application` is called with `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Refer the mention in documentation below for onCreate method of Application class.

> [public void onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate())
>
> Called when the application is starting,
> before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content
> providers) have been created